# Arduino Rubber ducky?

Tags: usb

So there is this hacking tool called a rubber ducky , the concept is that the device looks like a flash drive but the computer thinks it's a keyboard . According to what i know , a usb port has 4 wires , VCC GND and 2 for data , so i thought if it was possible to take a usb cable , cut it and connect it to the arduino accordingly , and send the computer that data so that he would think i connected a keyboard , and basicly create a fake reprogrammable keyboard

Comment: You mean buy an Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Micro and plug it in?

Comment: You can fake a keyboard using VUSB for AVR.

Comment: @Gerben I would never touch a solution like that even with someone else's barge pole. Bit-banged USB is very very nasty, and a 5V (non-USB) Arduino doesn't have a suitably compatible electrical interface to USB which risks damaging your hub or computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most Arduinos can't be a USB keyboard (not without some really nasty bit-banging code and dodgy electronics).

Some can, though - such as the Arduino Leonardo or the Arduino Micro. And you don't need to cut any cables, you just plug it in.

Comment: i meant like if i take a usb cable and cut it and connect the according wires of the usb cable to the arduino and sending data , any chance the computer can see this data and think a keyboard or mouse has been connected ?

Comment: Why take a cable and cut it? Just plug it direct into an Arduino that is designed for the job!

Comment: I mean sending raw data , since when i connect and arduino , it sends the pc certain bytes that tell the pc that is an arduino , but i want to trick the pc  into thinking that is a keyboard

Comment: So you mean plugging in an Arduino that is designed for the task, like the Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Micro? Do you actually have the faintest clue what an Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Micro actually are?